# Answered question appears as unanswered in lists

Tags: bug, accepted-answer

Of course it's possible that I misunderstand the rules, but this looks like a bug to me.

As I write this, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5809788/712765) has 238 votes and has an accepted answer with 44 votes. However, it shows up in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52917081/712765)'s "Related" list with the number 238 on a gray background, which I believe is supposed to mean it is unanswered.

[image: Related list]

It also shows up as unanswered in search results. My guess is it shows up unanswered wherever it appears in a list.

[image]

The question and accepted answer are over 7 years old, so it is not likely due to the state recently changing. Is this a bug? If not, what's the rule that makes this correct?

Comment: Blame caching maybe? :3

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I poked around in SEDE and the `AcceptedAnswerId` on the question is `NULL`.

Comment: @Stephen Did I say something?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ hmm, I guess blame [merging](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5809788/revisions) this time...

Comment: The grey background shows that no answer is accepted. It doesn't show that its unanswered.

Comment: Also note that the accepted answer is not pinned on the top.

Comment: Yes, @BlackThunder, so why does the question I'm talking about not have a filled in green box? It has, as I said in the post, an accepted answer.

Comment: At first glance it would seem to be because the agreed answer is not the most liked answers.